# How can I resolve this question about idea

Tags: intellij-idea

it starts the initial loading and then following is shown in the screen.After that it is vanished and program does not start.As you know ,I already have found this question in stack overflow,but there answers can't resolve my question.

I have changed the .vmoptions's max-memory to 512m.But the question still exist,I still cant't open the idea.

Comment: Try executing it from the terminal.  Many times if a program is failing to run it will report an error message in the terminal which isn't visible if you launch it from the GUI.

Comment: What error do you get? There is no screenshot in your question. As suggested above, run in the command line to see the errors in the console. Contact support for help: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/requests/new.